# Which mathematician set up a hypothesis which was proven in one of the French math magazines in 2003.

Tags: math-history, fake-proofs

Which mathematician set up a hypothesis which was proven in one of the French math magazines in 2003. and then the same mathematician declared in 2011. that the proof was false?

Comment: I cound not find the tag "general knowledge" ha ha...

Comment: A famous one is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Branges_de_Bourcia about the Riemann hypothesis